# Application throw error on Tomcat start with Java DXA 1.4 with Linux hosted server

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

We are facing issue with Java DXA 1.4 on Linux hosted services.
All microservices are running fine.

When we start tomcat it throws error:

> Could not load [net/sf/ehcache/version.properties] 
>   org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheCachingProvider@64c9b99f] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [net/sf/ehcache/version.properties]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access. 
>   catalina.log

Also in DXA logs we are getting error as:

> ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextServiceClaimsProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private

Moreover with the same services we are able to get page with all content in .Net DXA 1.4.

Please help to resolve this issue only specific to Java+ Tomcat.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386934/web-instance-already-stopped see if it helps

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Tomcat 8.0.36 is used: